# Angular Reactive Forms: Detect user input before the value changes

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I know that you can use the valueChanges observable in Angular Reactive Forms to detect if a value in the input field has already changed:

```
inputControl.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
    // fires when the input value has actually changed
});
```

However, is there a way to **subscribe** to an observable of when the user has pressed a key, *before* the value changes in the input?

I need to do this so I can apply dynamic validation, for example:

1. User presses a key
2. I need to know what that key is before I apply validation
3. Validation then works on the changed value of the input

Answer (score 2):

> is there a way to subscribe when the user has pressed a key,
>   before the value changes in the input?

onkeyup event :

```
 <input formControlName="yourcontrol" (keyup)="onKeyUp($event)">
```

## EDIT :

You need subscribe to event `keyup` on your *AbstractControl elememnt*.

see the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-if7w9w?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

You could also create a directive to access your element using `ElementRef` regarding what your requirements are.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to subscribe to keypresses on the form control only, not on the whole document.

Comment: Thanks again, but the example isn't a subscription to an observable (e.g. like in the `valueChanges` example), which is what I'm looking for. I'll try to make my question more clear on that. If it's definitely not possible that way, please include that your answer.